# How do I resolve "negative bitmapset member not allowed" error on redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a query where I'm creating virtual tables using WITH command but the code runs till second last table and when I include the last table it gives this  *Amazon Invalid operation: negative bitmapset member not allowed;*

My code is as:

```
semi_final_table
AS
(SELECT invoice_number ,
       DATE,
       CAST(quantity_shipped AS INT),
       CAST(revenue AS FLOAT),
       bill_number,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       serial,
       code1,
       code2,
       employeenum,
       slixID,
       account,
       state,
       business,
       promotion_code,
       'Name',
       SFAC,
       SFAC_long,
       part_of _package,
       category,
       pack_number
FROM (SELECT *,
             CASE
               WHEN 'Sales' then 'rep'
               ELSE business
             END AS business2,
             CASE
               WHEN UPPER(TRIM(business)) IN ('NURSING') THEN 'NURSING'
               WHEN UPPER(TRIM(business)) IN ('MBBS') THEN 'MEDICAL EDUCATION'
               WHEN UPPER(TRIM(business)) IN ('BAMS') THEN 'HEALTH PROFESSIONS'
               WHEN UPPER(TRIM(business)) = 'DNM' THEN 'MED ED PRACTICE'
               ELSE business
             END AS final_business
      FROM table2
      WHERE (employeenum) IS NOT NULL)
WHERE CAST(order_date AS DATE) < '2019-01-01'
AND   TRIM(employeenum) NOT IN ('2','3','4')
AND   UPPER(TRIM(slixid)) <> 'CAREER'
AND   (employeenum IN ('52','61') OR (UPPER(TRIM(region)) IN ('CENTRAL','SOUTHEAST','WEST') AND final_business IN ('NURSING',)) OR (UPPER(TRIM(region)) IN ('Northest','North') AND final_business IN ('MEDICAL EDUCATION'))))


    
select sum(revenue), lower(final_business) from semi_final_table group by lower(final_business);
```

After running this, I am getting this negative bitmapset error.

How can i resolve it?

Comment: Can you possibly reduce your example down in size so that it still generates the error, but removes superfluous content that isn't related to the error?

Comment: By the way, `UPPER(TRIM(region)) IN ('Northest','North')` will never be true.

Comment: This should generate a syntax error:  `final_business IN ('NURSING',)`.